# Is there any method to guarantee transaction from the user end

Tags: mongodb

Since MongoDB does not support transactions, is there any way to guarantee transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ti's one of the things you choose to forego when you choose a NoSQL solution.

If transactions are required, perhaps NoSQL is not for you.  Time to go back to ACID relational databases.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "guarantee transaction"?

There are two conepts in MongoDB that are similar;

- Atomic operations
- Using safe mode / **getlasterror** ...

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Last+Error+Commands

If you simply need to know if there was an error when you run an update for example you can use the **getlasterror** command, from the docs ...

> getlasterror is primarily useful for
>   write operations (although it is set
>   after a command or query too).  Write
>   operations by default do not have a
>   return code: this saves the client
>   from waiting for client/server
>   turnarounds during write operations. 
>   One can always call getLastError if
>   one wants a return code.
>
> If you're writing data to MongoDB on
>   multiple connections, then it can
>   sometimes be important to call
>   getlasterror on one connection to be
>   certain that the data has been
>   committed to the database. For
>   instance, if you're writing to
>   connection # 1 and want those writes to
>   be reflected in reads from connection #2, you can assure this by calling getlasterror after writing to
>   connection # 1.

Alternatively, you can use **atomic operations** for cases where you need to increment a value for example (like an upvote, etc.) more about that here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations

As a side note, MySQL's default storage engine doesn't have transaction either! :) 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB only supports atomic operations. There is no ways implement transaction in the sense of ACID *on top* of MongoDB. Such a transaction support must be implemented in the core. But you will never see full transaction support due to the CARP theorem. You can not have speed, durability and consistency at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately MongoDB does't support transaction out of the box, but actually you can implement ACID optimistic transactions on top on it. I wrote an example and some explanation on a [GitHub](https://github.com/rystsov/mongodb-transaction-example) page.